# hyperlink inheriting color, how to overcome

Tags: html, css

I am editing style.css of wordpress

and i want to display a hyperlink with white color i-e

```
<a class="viewall" href="/">View All</a>

.viewall {
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

But its still showing hyperlink with black color, as it is inheriting from above css defined..
How to overcome this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include style for "visited" as well.

```
   a.viewall, a.viewall:visited {
     color: #ffffff;
   }
```

[More Reading](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_visited.asp) -- includes styling unvisited, visited, hover, and active links.

Comment: Are you using *.viewall* or *a.viewall*?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add !important to your CSS style:

```
.viewall {
  color: #ffffff !important;
}
```